# Java Flight Recorder is not reporting any File I/O events

Tags: java, jmc, jfr

One of the advertised features of Java Flight Recorder is the ability to report the file created, read or force in the  File I/O tab in JMC 8.1

To test this feature, I created a small application that uses Apache commons-io to copy a large file from source to destination.

```
public static void fileCopy(String srcPath ,String destPath) throws IOException {
    File inpFile = new File(srcPath);
    if(inpFile.exists() && inpFile.isFile()) {
        File destFile = new File(destPath);
        FileUtils.copyFile(inpFile, destFile);
    }
}
```

On starting the FlightRecoder with the profile template, and observing the jfr file , I see no events in the File I/O template even though the copy operation took 11 seconds.

JVM used - **OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu.**

[image: Flight Recorder Screenshot]

```
 java -XX:StartFlightRecording=name=benchmark,filename=benchmark.jfr,settings=profile -jar filecopyer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I also retried after changing the File IO threshold to 0 ns in the profile.jfc template, and still no events are recorded.

There are simply 0 events captured for jdk.FileWrite , jdk.FileRead and jdk.FileForce.

I however do see events under jdk.NativeMethodSample , which commons-io ends up calling.

Sample application on github :
[Profiled application](https://github.com/localghost8080/JavaFlightRecordingDemo)

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the implementation of Files.copy, which Apache Commons seems to use, relies on async I/O to do the copying. See sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile::copy(...)

JFR doesn't currently instrument async I/O operations.

Comment: Thanks for this information. 
I was searching for good documentation on what various events are meant to represent. I didn't find any.

Is there documentation where it is mentioned that JFR doesn't currently instrument async I/O operations , that I can refer.

Comment: "Events for async I/O is an outage in JFR, because we haven't figured out how to model and implement them. " https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075813

Comment: I changed my code to use BufferedInputStream and FileInputStream instead of commons-io and used that to copy a large file with readNBytes(b[],off,len) and writeNBytes . Yet no events were recorded. 

Can you point me to the api which I can use that will cause jdk.FileRead and Write events to fire ? 

Also the openjdk bugs link is behind a password wall.

Comment: FileInputStream should work. You can see an example here: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/test/jdk/jdk/jfr/event/io/TestFileStreamEvents.java The threshold probably needs to be set to 0 ns. Sorry about the password, but I can't find anywhere it is public stated, so you have to take my word for it. I have worked on JFR for ten years in OpenJDK.

Comment: yes 0 for 'File I/O Threshold' needs